# Office 365 on Kiosk\Public workstations

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-office-2016

Background:

- Company wide transitioning to O365.
- All workstations are domain Joined.
- The public workstations are mainly used as lab\training workstations which everyone can use a standard account.

Question:

What solutions are available to have full office 2016 (looking more towards the Office 365 offering) on workstations used as public workstations?

Since office 365 is tied to a user account, is my only option to have two different Office solutions in the environment (o365 for end users, and standard key installation with public workstations)?

Comment: Simply solution is to purchase office 3016 for the public workstations and office 365 for all others, you won't enable to install both on a single machine

Comment: @Ramhound:  Office 3016 won't be available for another 1,000 years, even if Microsoft is still around and we're still using computers.  The OP may not be able to wait that long.  :-)

Comment: 2016, was to lazy to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft offers an O365 Kiosk solution - but they don't have the full office suite only the web versions for use.

If all your users already have a valid O365 logon with ProPlus subscription  - you can install Office in Shared Activation mode.  This doesn't count against the 5 activation that are allowed with their user activation.  Note, however - each user is still required to sign in and be validated they are authorized for use. If this is skipped Office will still run - but in reduced functionality mode (basically read only) with a nice red banner saying it's not licensed.

If they are using a shared account - then technically that account could be licensed for O365 use and activate it's copy of Office, but you still need one license for each account, and only one account per machine should be in use (using 5 activation for shared computers at the same time for 5 users would be a violation of the user agreement).

Outside of these - you have to use a volume licensing key and activate it per instillation instead of per user.